# Specifying colours for binary data using levelplot

Tags: r, matrix, binary, levelplot

I have raster data that is coded in binary, and I would like to use the `levelplot` in the `rasterVis` package to plot the data, such that 0 values are green and 1 values are red. I can't seem to find how to specify a colour for a value.

As an example,

```
# create a matrix with 0s and 1s  
nr <- 21
nc <- 11
m <- matrix(sample(0:1, nr*nc, replace=TRUE), nr, nc)
# plot the matrix
colour <- c("green", "red")
levelplot(m, col.regions=colour, margin = FALSE)
```

Which works fine, and produces this
[Binary matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkaTY.jpg)

But if I have matrices that happen to be all 0, or all 1,

```
m2 <- matrix(0, nr, nc)
levelplot(m2, col.regions=colour, margin = FALSE)
m3 <- matrix(1, nr, nc)
levelplot(m3, col.regions=colour, margin = FALSE)
```

I get the same plot, when what I want is for 0 values to be green and 1 values to be red.

[Matrix with only 0 or 1 values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4wq9.jpg)

How do I specify such that if it's 0, it comes out green, and if it's 1, it comes out red?

Comment: `levelplot` is not part of base R. Please mention the package name(s) you are using in your question.

Comment: @lmo Have just added it in

Comment: I don't have access to this package at the moment, so I can't test anything, but you might try something with `ifelse`. Maybe col=`ifelse(0, "green", "red")`. This technique works for base R plots, anyway. Check the help section: `?levelplot` to see if you adjust color types manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `ratify` to declare your `raster` data as a categorical variable (see [this example](http://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/#factor)):

```
library(rasterVis)

nr <- 21
nc <- 11
m <- matrix(sample(c(0, 1), nr * nc, replace=TRUE), nr, nc)
r <- raster(m)

r <- ratify(r)
rat <- levels(r)[[1]]
rat$code <- c(0, 1)
levels(r) <- rat


levelplot(r)
```

[image: binary raster]